# Mounting an existing volume from a Kubeflow Pipeline: kfp.VolumeOP creates a new volume instead of creating a PVC to existing volume

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am new to KubeFlow and trying to port / adapt an existing solution to run in KubeFlow pipelines. The issue I am solving now is that the existing solution shared data via a mounted volume. I know this is not the best practice for components exchanging data in KubeFlow however this will be a temporary proof of concept and I have no other choice.

I am facing issues with accessing an existing Volume from the pipeline. I am basically running the code from KubeFlow documentation [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/sdk/release-1.8/samples/contrib/volume_ops/volumeop_parallel.py), but pointing to an existing K8S Vo

```
def volume_op_dag():
vop = dsl.VolumeOp(
    name="shared-cache",
    resource_name="shared-cache",
    size="5Gi",
    modes=dsl.VOLUME_MODE_RWO
)
```

The Volume shared-cache exists:

[image]

However when I run the pipeline a new volume is created:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I obviously don't want to create a new volume every time I run the pipeline but instead mount an existing one.

Edit: Adding KubeFlow versions:

- kfp (1.8.13)
- kfp-pipeline-spec (0.1.16)
- kfp-server-api (1.8.3)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the function [`kfp.onperm.mount_pvc`](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.extensions.html#kfp.onprem.mount_pvc). You can find values for the arguments `pvc_name` and `volume_name` via the console command
`kubectl -n <your-namespace> get pvc`.
The way you use it is by writing the component as if the volume is already mounted and following the example from the [doc](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.extensions.html#kfp.onprem.mount_pvc) when binding it in the pipeline:

```
train = train_op(...)
train.apply(mount_pvc('claim-name', 'pipeline', '/mnt/pipeline'))
```

Also note, that both the volume and the pipeline must be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use already existing volume using the following step:

```
 volume_name = 'already_existing_volume name'

#Instead of using this (which every time creates a new volume),
 task = create_step_prepare_data().add_pvolumes({data_path: vop.volume})

# use this (just by adding dsl.PipelineVolume(pvc=volume_name))
 task = create_step_prepare_data().add_pvolumes({data_path: dsl.PipelineVolume(pvc=volume_name)})
```